# Построение индекса по пустому ключу и интервалу

Tags: postgresql

Существует запрос

```
select count(id) from contact 
where  now() - last_presence <= interval '120 sec' and accessroleid <> (select id from accessrole where code = 'Client')
```

Где last_presence = дата (timestamp)
accesroleid = ключ в таблицу-справочник (varchar(36))

База с индексами по полю accesroleid и/или last_presence все еще использует seq scan. Можно ли создать индекс для данного запроса с учетом того что запрос изменять нельзя и подзапрос возвращает пустоту?

Версия базы 9.6, в таблице contact 1.8м строк

Анализ запроса:

```
QUERY PLAN
Aggregate  (cost=214485.84..214485.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=486.313..486.313 rows=1 loops=1)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Seq Scan on accessrole  (cost=0.00..1.18 rows=1 width=90) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
          Filter: ((code)::text = 'Client'::text)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 14
  ->  Seq Scan on contact  (cost=0.00..212245.39 rows=895708 width=37) (actual time=486.309..486.309 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (((accessroleid)::text <> ($0)::text) AND ((now() - (last_presence)::timestamp with time zone) <= '00:02:00'::interval))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1836984
Planning time: 0.552 ms
Execution time: 486.406 ms
```

Comment: Нельзя, потому что вы делаете выборку по динамически вычисляемым значениям, которые в принципе невозможно индекисровать

Comment: А вот если написать `last_presence >= now() - interval '120 sec'` то возможно индекс по last_presence заработает

Comment: А ещё лучше посчитать дату где-нибудь заранее и подставить её готовую в запрос, чтобы никаких вычислений в запросе вообще не было

Comment: @andreymal Согласен если мы говорим о поле last_presence, а планировщик случаем не может сделать сортировку сначала по полю accessroleid? Я где-то читал что он по идее должен именно такие сравнения обрабатывать в первую очередь

Comment: @andreymal в индексе использовать `now()` база не позволяет, только immutable нужны, а по поводу подсчета то хорошо было бы, если бы я имел доступ к этой функции, я ее только со стороны базы вижу =/